# Devextreme Angular modal dialog

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

How do I make a modal dialog asking user to confirm deleting row in a data grid - devextreme.angular?

Looked at their Dialogs doc section - I dont see anything simple like the one I need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have `allowDeleting` true, it will show modal automatically

```
    <dxo-editing 
         mode="row"
         [allowUpdating]="true"
         [allowDeleting]="true"
         [allowAdding]="true">
    </dxo-editing>
```

[image]
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/Angular/Light/